# Efficient way of looping through list of dictionaries and appending items into column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Here is MRE:

```
data = [
    {'1':20},
    {'1':10},
    {'1':40},
    {'1':14},
    {'1':33}
]
```

What I am trying to do is loop through each dictionary and append each value to a column in a dataframe.

right now I am doing

```
import pandas as pd
lst = []
for item in data:
    lst.append(item['1'])

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":lst})
```

outputting:

```
    col1
0   20
1   10
2   40
3   14
4   33
```

Yes this is what I want however I have over 1M dictionaries in a list. Is it most efficient way?

**EDIT**:
`pd.DataFrame(data).rename(columns={'1':'col1'})`
works perfectly for above case however what if data looks like this?

```
data = [
    {'1':
     {'value':20}},
    {'1':
     {'value':10}},
    {'1':
      {'value':40}},
    {'1':
      {'value':14}},
    {'1':
      {'value':33}}]
```

so I would use:

```
lst = []
for item in data:
    lst.append(item['1']['value'])

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":lst})
```

is there more efficient way for list of dictionary that contain dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea is pass `data` to `DataFrame` cosntructor and then use `rename`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data).rename(columns={'1':'col1'})
print (df)
   col1
0    20
1    10
2    40
3    14
4    33
```

If is necessary filtering use list comprehension and add parameter `columns`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([x['1'] for x in data], columns=['col1'])
print (df)
   col1
0    20
1    10
2    40
3    14
4    33
```

EDIT: For new data use:

```
data = [
    {'1':
     {'value':20}},
    {'1':
     {'value':10}},
    {'1':
      {'value':40}},
    {'1':
      {'value':14}},
    {'1':
      {'value':33}}]

df = pd.DataFrame([x['1']['value'] for x in data], columns=['col1'])
print (df)
   col1
0    20
1    10
2    40
3    14
4    33
```

Or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([x['1'] for x in data]).rename(columns={'value':'col1'})
print (df)
   col1
0    20
1    10
2    40
3    14
4    33
```

Comment: Thanks! But what about for list of nested dictionaries? I've edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

@jezrael's answer is correct but to be more specific with `col`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.add_prefix('col'))
```

Output:

```
   col1
0    20
1    10
2    40
3    14
4    33
```

Comment: Thanks! how come when you enter add_prefix('col') it assign 'col1' as column name?

Comment: @lmbloo It adds `col` to beginning!

Comment: you mean index is named `col`?

Comment: @lmbloo No, adds `col` in the beginning of every column name